# Issue in separating multiple email address using semicolon

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a input field where I can add multiple email address with semicolon as separator. According to [email address wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address) email address can contain a semicolon in it that is "()<>[]:,;-/=?^"@example.org is a valid email.

when I use `"abc;xyz"@example.com;hhh@exam.com.split(";")` am getting `"\"abc"` , `"xyz\"@example.com"`, `"hhh@exam.com"`. My requirement is I need to get `"abc;xyz@example.com"` and `hhh@exam.com` only.

Question is even though email address contains semicolon how to check and split at the end of email address, so that i will get complete email address not a part of it. Please suggest. Here is plnkr https://plnkr.co/edit/Lc6HNFzT0hBtVwp0EghG?p=preview. Please suggest.

```
$scope.validateEmailAddress = function() {
    var regex = /^((?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x20\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9]))\.){3}(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\]))/;
  
    if ($scope.email.indexOf(';') > 0) {
                            
        $scope.emailArray = $scope.email.split(";")
        for (var x = 0; x < $scope.emailArray.length; x++) {
                var emailId = $scope.emailArray[x];
                emailId = emailId.trim();
                if(reg.test(emailId)){
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I suggest you use a different symbol for seperating two email while entering.

Comment: ok, There will be colons in email & colons are the separators. Then how can you identify 2 separate emails? As you did, it will show 3 emails. Sorry i do not know to fix it.

Comment: Actually if you look at RFC 2882 there is very little that can't be used in an email address. I did come up with a regex that would parse a list of email addresses but it's over 4000 characters long and uses Perl regex syntax.